# Application Timeout After 10 minutes Android

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I want to timeout mysession from my web service if the user doesn't use the application for >=10 minutes. If the user doesn't use the application after this delay i want my session to close. I cater with it the following way

```
    c = Calendar.getInstance(); 

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    //lastActivity = new Date().getTime();

   second = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

   Log.i("Second: ",Integer.toString(second));

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {

    int now = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    if (now - second >= 10) {
         Log.i("/******* /n TIMEOUT /n *******/",Integer.toString(now));
    }

    super.onResume();
}
```

am i doing it the right way or is there a method in android to check if application is 10 minutes inactive ?

Comment: AFAIK there is no suchs method...

Comment: sandkasten is wrong I believe, but why are you trying to make an Android application behave like a web browser? What type of application are you writing? What state information does it need to remember when its UI thread resumes before and after the 10 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong because of if second srtore at 12:12:12 and check condition on12:13:11 then what happen u have to check totaltimestamp dear